# JOHN CULVINER FILE DOWNLOAD with dynamic form not working

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a dynamic form on submit I call the plugin like below

```
var method = "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.
var path = "downloadExcel.obj";
var formDownload = document.createElement("form");
formDownload.setAttribute("method", method);
formDownload.setAttribute("action", path);
formDownload.setAttribute("id", "fileDownloadForm");
var custhiddenField = document.createElement("input");
custhiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
custhiddenField.setAttribute("name", "customerId");
custhiddenField.setAttribute("value", customerId); // VALUE IS GETTING UPDATED HERE
formDownload.appendChild(custhiddenField);
```

...............................................................................
//On printing the form here on console I get the updated formDownload
...........................................................................

```
formDownload.submit = 
$.fileDownload($('#fileDownloadForm').prop('action'), {
httpMethod: "POST",
data: $('#fileDownloadForm').serialize(),
preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
});
```

Now I am able to download the file first time successfully but when I try to download second time [without refreshing the page], my variable formDownload is having the updated data but when I debug inside jquery.fileDownload [settings.data] still have the old data. Henceforth downloading the file for previous customer again and again

Comment: What is the problem? How do think `pricing` should be updated?

Comment: Just edited the question, let me know if I am making sense:)

Comment: From what I see, you need to update something in the form before doing the post. I think it is a javascript issue, not java/backend issue. But from what you've shown so far it is not clear what and how can be updated

Comment: Let me explain a bit why I did this way....business doesn't want user to click twice for downloading EXCEL FILE. So after entering the form data like customer Id etc USER click SUBMIT on which I make JQUERY POST request do back-end validations [see above method extractPricing] and sent JSON response if error, if success I show user the count as MODAL box, if they click YES, than I grab new values from text box, calendar etc and create a dynamic form and submit it [on JAVA side handled by downloadExcel() SPRING method]

Comment: As per your comment it is not a javascript issue as I am able to see that new values are getting populate in  JSP side see below:
var custInfoArray = ($('#customerId').val()).split("-");
var customerId = custInfoArray[0];

Comment: Where do you set customerid in the form. If in this line: `custhiddenField.setAttribute("name", "customerId");', then you don't need quotes. If somewhere else, you need to show the code.

Comment: I added the complete code above

Comment: It would help if your question described more succinctly the problem instead of just naming the technologies you're using ("Java Spring JSP").

Comment: Done!!! Let me know if more details need to be provided

Answer (score 0):

In the code where you say:

```
 //re-intialize variables
 var custInfoArray = ($('#customerId').val()).split("-");
 var customerId = custInfoArray[0];
 var regionInfoArray = ($('#regionId').val()).split("-");
.....
```

You don't reinitialize them. if you have them defined somewhere else, you define new variables in the function scope.  Try removing `var` in front of `customerid` and other variables used in `POST`.

Try the following instead:

```
//re-intialize variables
 custInfoArray = ($('#customerId').val()).split("-");
 customerId = custInfoArray[0];
 regionInfoArray = ($('#regionId').val()).split("-");
.....
```

Comment: I re-intialize the variable as I thought I was passing the wrong values from front-end but it turns out variable values are passed correctly from front-end [I remove the re-initialize code but still same error]. PLEASE SEE THE CHANGED CODE ABOVE. Even the HttpServletRequest is having the old values [see below].

@RequestMapping(value = "/downloadExcel.obj", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public void downloadExcel(@ModelAttribute("pricing") Pricing pricing, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)

Comment: This problem is only happening if I am not refreshing the page, if say I refresh the page after every successful file download everything works correctly.

Comment: Where is 'customerid' defined in your code? Your best bet is to see in debugger what are the values of `customerid` and other variables are at every step and what is being sent. That will help to pinpoint the problem. Othewise we can just guess.

Comment: Edited with more clarified suggestion but the problem could be somewhere else.

Comment: YOU are right the problem is the way I am using John Culviner file download. My dynamic form has the updated values but somehow when I debug inside fileDownload.js it still using the old values

 `$.fileDownload($('#fileDownloadForm').prop('action'), {
                   httpMethod: "POST",
                 data: $('#fileDownloadForm').serialize(),
                 preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
                        failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
                   });`

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid mistake, correct code should be:

```
  $.fileDownload($('#fileDownloadForm').prop('action'), {
            httpMethod: "POST",
            data: $(formDownload).serialize(), //this is changed
            preparingMessageHtml: "We are preparing your report, please wait...",
            failMessageHtml: "There was a problem generating your report, please try again."
     });
```